# Linux support for external Thunderbolt3 10gbE adapters

Tags: linux, ethernet, thunderbolt

I am investigating external Thunderbolt3 10gbE adapters to be used with Linux. i would love to have a device which is fully supported in Linux Kernel and has decent performance.

My current thoughts are about the QNAP QNA-T310G1T, which seems to be based on the Marvell(Aquantia) AQtion chipset (AQC-100, AQC-107, AQC-108).

The ones I found until now are

- QNAP QNA-T310G1T (confirmed [Marvell AQtion AQC107](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwit1uODlYaAAxXe3QIHHVEqCF8QFnoECAoQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fobjects.icecat.biz%2Fobjects%2Fmmo_65138090_1652868042_3686_7192.pdf&usg=AOvVaw1hUmK9qK6G03oyLQPp9ZVo&opi=89978449))
- [OWC Thunderbolt 3 10G Ethernet Adapter][1] ([evidence for no Linux support](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2459111), but [the OWC website suggests it also is based on AQC107](https://eshop.macsales.com/Service/Knowledgebase/Article/21/858/OWC-Thunderbolt-3-10G-Ethernet-Adapter-Driver))
- [Sabrent Thunderbolt 3 Ethernet Adapter TH-S3EA](https://sabrent.com/products/th-s3ea) ([Linux support](https://downloads.sabrent.com/product/th-s3ea-linux-driver-2-4-3-2/))

Does anyone have solid experience with any of those adapters, or has some other brand or driver to recommend? (here is a review from [Jiri Brejcha](https://www.jiribrejcha.net/2022/07/sabrent-thunderbolt-3-to-10-gbps-ethernet-adapter-the-fastest-multigigabit-adapter-for-your-mac/), and there are some [reported issues with AQC108](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=278303)).

Answer (score 1):

I don't have direct experience, but I'd run a mile from anything without in-tree drivers.  However it seems like all three of yours are Aquantia-based and [drivers are in-tree](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/networking/device_drivers/ethernet/aquantia/atlantic.html) (since kernel 4.11 apparently). I've run motherboards with Aquantia 2.5G/5G PCIe NICs and they have been fine using in-tree drivers, but I can't speak for the 10G NICs.  I wouldn't rate them as highly as Intel NICs, but not sure any of those are available as external devices.

Being Thunderbolt shouldn't make much difference - these are just PCIe NICs behind a Thunderbolt bridge.